# What does (int ) represent that comes after new Vector<Object Type> (int )?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

I am just studying some code and I come across something like the following

```
Vector<Fruit> tables = new Vector<Fruit>(int );
```

Inside the ( ) is some int variable. What is it supposed to represent? Fruit is a class, so it holds the type of Fruit.

Comment: *"Constructs an empty vector with the specified initial capacity and with its capacity increment equal to zero."* - Sets up the `Vector`s initial buffer size, this can make the vector faster when adding values to it, as it doesn't need to re-allocate the internal buffer if it thinks it's running out of space.  `Vector` is generally deprecated in favor of the newer `Collections` API

Answer (score 1):

The `int` is a default initial size (or *capacity*). The [`Vector` constructor Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28int%29) reads,

> public Vector(int initialCapacity)
>
> Constructs an empty vector with the specified initial capacity and with its capacity increment equal to zero.

Also, I would suggest you prefer the `List` interface (and `ArrayList` implementation) over `Vector`.

Comment: No. I mean an *initial* size, not a *maximum* size. `Vector` will grow as you add elements (when you pass the *current* size). The default size is 10.

Comment: And by initial size, like the starting amount of elements i it can hold when it starts, correct? So if the i is 5 for example, it can hold 5 objects of Fruit at the start, correct?

Comment: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initial) says **initial** is *occurring at the beginning of something*. So yes, the capacity when it starts. There may be a check that prevents you from declaring an initial capacity less then 10.

Answer (score 0):

Its initial capacity which means first time it will create with this size. If you are not sure what value to use can use constructor without int. new Vector();. But if you know approximate size of you are going to use, then it is better to pass that value for performance.

Java gives normally a default intial capacity of 10 , which means it has keeps 10 memory location allocted to your vector. And increase it when you add elements near 10. So it is overhead, allocating memory again and again if this size is very small. However,if this value is very high, and you didn't use it, its wastage of memory.

So, if you know approximate size  you are going to use, you can pass acccordingly.

Use vector only if you are dealing with some legacy api, having vector as parameters. Else, better to go for List.

Comment: yes, memory places its allocate for holding value. However, it is dynamic for better performance it allocates some memory already.

Comment: So if the i is 5 for example, it can hold 5 objects of Fruit at the start, correct?

Comment: yes, it will not affect you , actually its internally handled by java. Even after 5 , you need not to change size or something, you can keep on adding as usual. Just it has performance impact. Its like when you try to add 6th element, java will resize it internally.

Comment: if you are not writing very performance extensive application then simple use construtor Vector(); Only if you know size before hand then provide this value.